# nodejs on windows: nmp install does not download modules

Tags: node.js

I have installed a 64bit nodejs on my windows7 (classical installation, no errors during installation)

I created a simple package.json

```
{
"name":"chat",
"version":"0.0.1",
"private":"true",
"dependecies":{
    "socket.io":"0.9.16",
    "express":"3.1.0",
}
```

}

then install it with

```
npm install
```

and... Nothing: no packages are downloaded !

(if I make an error in the package.json, I got errors messages at npm install)
Everything seems to be fine, except that npm install does not install anything.

and of course when trying to luch a nodejs project, I got:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your `package.json`, it should be "dependencies".

Make sure to generate your `package.json` with `npm init`, so to avoid this kind of problems.